# Authentication, Compare data input from client side with mySql in server side using express JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, typescript, express

I need help comparing data and return `true` or `false` from the cilent side to server side to check an email is valid or not. In the client side, the client will enter an email and click a button to verify, then server will check the database if the email exist or not. If the email exists the the user is valid, and if the email doesn't exist then the client is not valid and cannot proceed to the next page. I'm not really familiar with express and some mysql query. I tested my code in postman application and it returns `valid` everytime. Here is some sample emails from mySql.

[image]

I'm using `app.post` command in my javascript express code, but looks like i'm doing it wrong and i wrote the `if` statement incorrectly. In postman application when i check it, it always returns `valid` and in client side i cannot authenticate with any email. I'm not sure what condition should i put because i'm not really familiar with express.

```js
app.post('/verifyEmail', (req, res) => {
  var email = req.body.email;
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM email WHERE email = ?'; //incorrect condition checking
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (email == null || !email) { //incorrect condition checking
      throw err;
      res.send('invalid');
    }
    console.log('valid');
    res.send('valid');
  })
})
```

In the client side, i'm using Angular with typescript.

```js
//service.ts
email: string[];
getEmailAPI(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/verifyEmail")
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}

//component.ts
Email = [];
isVerified: boolean;
getEmailAPI() {
  this.QuestionService.getEmailAPI().subscribe(
    data => console.log('All email', this.Email = data),
    error => console.log('server returns error')
  );
}

verifyEmail(formValue) {
  this.AppService.getEmailAPI().subscribe(
    data => {
      if (data) {
        // do whatever needed is with returned data
        this.isVerified = true;
      } else {
        this.isVerified = false;
      }
    },
    error => console.log('server returns error')
  );
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<form #emailVerification='ngForm' ngNativeValidate>
  <label>Please Enter Your Email Below</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" required/>
  <button type="submit" (click)="verifyEmail(emailVerification.value)">VERIFY</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me, please? Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will always get valid since you are checking whether the email variable is null and your end result should return the json.Since in your client you're going to get the json. Change the code to following

```
 app.post('/verifyEmail', (req, res) => {
  var email = req.body.email;
  let sql = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM email WHERE email = ?';
  let query = db.query(sql, [email],(err, result) => {
    if (result[0].count == 1) {
      res.json({
        "data": "valid"
      })
    } else {

      res.json({
        "data": "invalid"
      })

    }
  });
});
```